strafe with turtlesim
I used to be able to do the following (in humble on Ubuntu 22.04) and get the turtlesim to strafe (move in the y direction)
ros2 topic pub /turtle1/cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist "{linear: {x: 0.0, y: 1.0, z: 0.0}, angular: {x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0}}"

the command works fine (for forward movement) if i change as follows:
ros2 topic pub /turtle1/cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist "{linear: {x: 1.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0}, angular: {x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0}}"

I have moved to jazzy on ubuntu 24.04 and this no longer works.
